# Manipulating the Control register

Tags: c, assembly, nios

can any one help me with how this code can affect the value in register ctl0 (disregarding the reserved bits). here is the code

```
rdctl r6,ctl0
andi r6, r6, 0x0006
wrctl ctl0, r6
```

Comment: What don't you understand about this code? It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I dont understand the question clearly. Is the answer : The value in ctl0 is and of r6 and 0x0006?

Comment: do you think this is rite?

Comment: You tell us - you have the user manual for your controller.

Comment: I am really not sure about the answer, I have the user manual but cant really find the answer

Comment: Can any one tell me how to undo this operation? How to get the original value of ctlo?

Comment: That's a separate question. But the answer is simple: you can't. It's overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent C pseudocode would be:

```
r6 = ctl0;         // rdctl r6, ctl0
r6 = r6 & 0x0006;  // andi r6, r6, 0x0006
ctl0 = r6;         // wrctl ctl0, r6
```

So, in other words,

```
ctl0 = ctl0 & 0x0006;
```

Comment: Can any one tell me how to undo this operation? How to get the original value of ctlo?